# Angular best practice for getting an object by id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have been using Angular for a while now and have noticed there are various ways to get a single object when a set of objects are already loaded onto memory.

For these cases I have loaded my list of objects into `$rootScope` so I minimize the `$http` calls to the db.

For example, I have done this:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in filteredTasks = (tasks | filter:{id: routeParams.taskId} | limitTo: 10 | filter:{title: tasks.search_tasks}">
   <div">{{ task.title }}</div>
</div
```

Or it could happen in the controller:

```
.controller('TasksCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    ...
    for (i=0;i<$rootScope.tasks.length;i++) {
        if ($rootScope.tasks[i].id == $routeParams.taskId) $scope.task = $rootScope.tasks[i];
    };
    ...
});
```

My question is if there is a preferred approach in terms of performance (or some other metric such as standard practice), as I guess any method will involve iterating on the Array of tasks at some point.

Comment: Depending on the size of the list you could send it as a map (id -> object). In JSON it's a plain object. Then just access it using `data[someId]`)

Comment: You mean map the array of objects by id following the initial http call?

Comment: Send them like that from the server. But yes, even client-side, instead of looping through them every time you need one why not just loop once?